# Cannot launch Python3 Script using .desktop file in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: bash, scripts, python, .desktop

I am a beginner in both Python and Ubuntu.
I was trying to launch a python script to display Tkinter GUI using Ubuntu `.desktop` file.
But it won't run instead it shows the file in editor.

Below are my codes, please help me if something is wrong in it.

**.desktop file code**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=tkinter
Exec=/home/roshan/Documents/python/python_tkinter/testscript.py
Icon=/home/roshan/Documents/python/python_tkinter/iconfile.png
Type=Application
```

**testscript.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3 
   
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.quitButton = tk.Button(self,text='Quit',command = self.quit)
        self.quitButton.grid()
    

app = Application()
app.master.title('Sample Application')
app.mainloop()
```

Note:

- `#!/usr/bin/env python` also works for me.
- `./testscript.py` worked using terminal.
- I have made `testscript.py` file as executable.
- I have tried by making `.desktop` file as executable too, but that also did not worked.

I followed few tutorials online as well on this, but no luck! for me.

Thank You.

Comment: Have you tried adding "Terminal=true" to your .desktop file?

Comment: Try `Exec=python3 /home/roshan/Documents/python/python_tkinter/testscript.py`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
Exec=python3 /home/roshan/Documents/python/python_tkinter/testscript.py
```

And in case your script uses other files in the same directory, so add a path:

```
Path=/home/roshan/Documents/python
```

This worked for me with an included Glade file as in:  `builder.add_from_file("UI.glade")`